# ionic v2 GIF cant display on ionic view

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic2

My GIF can show up in google chrome by ionic serve,but it cant show up in ionic view mode,my code is beneath. Plz help me QWQ

```
<div >
 <img width="100" height="100" id="setup" src="../assets/setup.gif" (click)="gotoSetup()">
 <img width="100" height="100" id="record" src="../assets/record.gif" (click)="gotoRecord()">
 <img width="100" height="100" id="exercise" src="../assets/sport.gif" (click)="gotoexercise()">
 <img width="100" height="100" id="food" src="../assets/food.gif" (click)="gotoFood()">

</div>
```

[first picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNuBR.jpg)

The GIF should look like this(this is on the google chrome by ionic serve)

[second picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRtOu.jpg)

But it didnt show up in ionic view properly

Comment: what if you change it to something else (.png?)

Comment: It only shows up in IONIC VIEW when I put them by css.However,I want to put them in html and ts way. Any suggest~~~